# call render partial from view in elixir

Tags: rendering, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm learning Elixir with Phoenix and just got stuck in a pretty dumb point. I want to call the render of a partial from inside my index template the following way:

```
#index.html.slim

- for element_here  <- array_here do
  = render MyApp.SharedView, "_game.html.slim", element: element_here
```

For this I created a View called shared_view.ex that looks like this:

```
defmodule MyApp.SharedView do
  use MyApp.Web, :view
  def render("game", _assigns), do: "/shared/_game.html.slim"
end
```

I expected it go through the loop rendering shared/_game.html.slim, which I copy here:

```
.col-md-4.portfolio-item
  a href="#"
    img.img-responsive alt="" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" /
  h3
    a href="#"  Project Name
  p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.
```

But nothing is being rendered. And I'm not getting an error neither. It just render the stuffs before and after that.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. There's no route or controller action connected to "_game" partial because I didn't think it was neccesary (I'm used to rails and it works this way there).

Comment: Try `= for` instead of `- for`.

Comment: nope. Same thing.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure about that? `- for` will ignore the output of the html inside it which would cause "It just render the stuffs before and after that.".

Comment: It looks like this, @Dogbert: 

= for element_here  <- array_here do
  = render MyApp.SharedView, "_game.html.slim", element: element_here

Comment: Never used slim, but are you sure you need to write `"_game.html.slim"` and not just `"_game.html"`. With eex, you don't put the eex part. Also overriding render in MyApp.SharedView is unneeded isnt' it?

Comment: Also, did you and try it in the console? `Phoenix.View.render(MyApp.SharedView, "_game.html", element: %{})`

Comment: Now I'm actually using only "game", @radubogdan. And on console i get undefined error: (UndefinedFunctionError) function Phoenix.View.render/2 is undefined (module Phoenix.View is not available)

Comment: What does `Phoenix.View.render` say? You should have an error and then it should say something like: `Did you mean one of:`. I'm curious to see the arity of render

Comment: No, actually this is the whole Error message: 
(UndefinedFunctionError) function Phoenix.View.render/3 is undefined (module Phoenix.View is not available)
    Phoenix.View.render(MyApp.SharedView, "game", [element: "something"])

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your issue on my project, but it works as expected. All important issues are listed above - you should put `=` before `for element_here..` in template and you shouldn't use '.slim' part in `render` call. Also, it works even without that custom `render` function. Are you sure you have elements to show? Is there an option to take a look at your code? Also, what if you put simple text instead of rendering partial - would it work? I understand that these questions are rather dumb, but there should be no issues

Comment: Also, please try running that `Phoenix.View.render` command in phoenix console(you tried it in simple elixir console I believe), which can be started by `iex -S mix` from project's folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turned out to be a spelling issue. There were two problems:

1. Slim extension should not be explicit, as @radubogdan explained.
2. Loop should be added using `= for` instead of `- for`, as @Dogbert said.

In the end it looks like this:

index.html.slim

```
= for element_here  <- array_here do
  = render MyApp.SharedView, "_game.html", element: element_here
```

shared_view.ex

```
defmodule MyApp.SharedView do
  use MyApp.Web, :view
  def render("game", _assigns), do: "/shared/_game.html.slim"
end
```

_game.html.slim

```
.col-md-4.portfolio-item
  a href="#"
    img.img-responsive alt="" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" /
  h3
    a href="#"  Project Name
   p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.
```